# Simulate Alpha Decay

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, radiation-hardening

[Alpha Decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_decay) is a kind of radiation decay where every time the atom "decays", it loses a helium nucleus (an alpha particle). This means that an atom loses 2 protons and 2 neutrons each time. Your task is to simulate this, including the problems that occur during alpha decay.

Given two integers as input, \$m\$ and \$p\$, where \$1 < p < m\$, count down in steps of 4 and 2 respectively until either \$m\$ or \$p\$ is equal to or less than 1. At this point, you should output the number which has not yet reached 1.

In order to mimic radioactive decay, however, your program should work when up to any 2 characters are removed from your program. These characters are chosen with uniform probability, and (obviously) chosen without replacement. "Up to" means that the number of characters removed can either be 0, 1 or 2, and your program should work when any number of characters between 0, 1 and 2 are removed.

By "work" it means that, your program, modified or not, should perform the task as specified. Programs may error, so long as the correct output is produced.

Input and output formats are liberal, so long as it's covered by the [defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), it's allowed.

The shortest code in bytes (without characters removed) wins!

### Test Cases

```
m, p     => output
100, 20  => 60
101, 100 => 50
45, 2    => 41
2000, 80 => 1840
57, 23   => 13
80, 40   => 0
81, 40   => 1
81, 41   => 1
43, 42   => 20
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but as far as I can see you are immediatly eliminating all the non-golfing languages, as the syntax would instantly be invalid if characters were to be removed.

Comment: @WheatWizard When any two characters are removed, I'll edit that in

Comment: I'm confused as to why the second case outputs `50`, shouldn't it output `48`?  And the 5th case `9` instead of `13`?

Comment: If those test cases are just errora and I my understanding is correct, [this](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/98OARQoAzExMVwKVAJ2dtQzS0FBj8tBO0bRHsJR0dTSsNK00la0t9IFYkMg1tY11EDh42LrGtrYgNwFM44aZsGMo9Ss////GxgY/Dcy/m9qDgA "Klein – Try It Online") should be a solution.  I need to go to sleep though so I will check back tomorrow.

Comment: @WheatWizard The progression goes like [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1dHoUDBViG1LDFHIzOvoLREQ1OTqzwjMydVIaSoNNWKizMzTSFXwcZWwdBKIakoNTEbLFKAKpKroGurYMLFWQCijYB0UWZeiQbIbM3//6MNDQx1FAwNDGIB), \$m = 1\$ when \$p = 50\$, not 48. Note that the countdown continues "until either \$m\$ or \$p\$ is *equal to or less* than 1"

Comment: Oh why is it less than or equal to 1 rather than zero?  That seems quite odd to me.

Comment: @WheatWizard Because, when I wrote this question 3 years ago, I went with 1 rather than 0. Not entirely sure why, but if I'd hazard a guess, I'd say because \$m\$ and \$p\$ represent mass and proton numbers, they can't reach 0 as all elements have at least \$m, p \ge 1\$

Comment: Unless a programming language has some form of redundancy implemented, this challenge is probably impossible in that language. I can see that someone will create a language for this, which is prohibited by standard loopholes. So this is probably impossible with the program decay constraint.

Comment: @Joao-3 There are a lot of existing languages with redundancy implementations. After all, see Wheat Wizard's comment above - the implementation isn't quite correct, but it's very similar

Comment: The description of the radiation hardening says and 2 characters are removed.  Does this include newlines?

Comment: @JPeroutek Yes, any two characters could be removed

Comment: How would this work with answers with multiple files?